# How to add external product url to woocommerce from a metadata by function.php

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using Woocommerce for products. All products are imported automatically by a plugin.
now i input external product url for affilliate shop and change in the source product link

affilliate link format is:

> external product url= website address + metadata
>
> ```
> website address: example.com      
> metadata: get_post_meta($post->ID, 'affkey',true)  
> product url woocommerce meta data: _product_url
> ```

```
function set_external( $post_id ){    
$mid_var = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'affkey',true); if(isset($mid_var) && !empty($mid_var)) { get_post_meta ($post->ID, 'affkey',ture);   
    $product_url= "example.com".$mid_var;  
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_url', true );    
}
```

i need in function get meta key and add to website address then input in product url in woocommerce

> Note: I have all of the above and it is a fixed link

But I don't know where and how to do it

Comment: Is this data currently stored in post meta and you don't know how to display it on the frontend? Or do you mean that this plugin recieves the data but you don't know how to store it? What is this plugin called? Remember, 3rd party plugins such as WooCommerce are offtopic here, we cannot help you with plugin support, you should go to the vendor for help

Comment: That data is currently stored in Meta Post and there is no need to discuss the plugin recieves the data
We want to save this stored data by applying the changes described in the product url field on woocommerce (save on _product_url metadata)

Comment: Did you mean the product attribute? Although I am not sure where is the product url stored finally because it is imported by a tool. It sounds like it should be a product attribute. Maybe you could give this a try: suppose you get the product with `global $product;`  You may `var_dump()` to see if the meta fields exists in `$product->get_attributes();` If so, you may try to update by method `set_attributes()`. See if it is what you are looking for.

Comment: It is not a product attribute. it is External product url